# Python: Comprimir un numpy array de NxNx2 y almacenarlo en disco

Tags: python, array, numpy, almacenamiento

Tengo un numpy array de dimensiones NxNx2 y necesito comprimirlo y guardar el comprimido en disco. Es posible? Y de ser así, cómo accedo a los datos después?

Comment: Bienvenida Laura a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`savez_compressed()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html), esta función te permite salvar uno o más objetos (no solo arrays de numpy) en un único archivo contenedor con el algoritmo `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` :

```
ejemplo1 = np.random.rand(3, 3, 2)
ejemplo2 = np.random.rand(3, 3, 2)

np.savez_compressed('mis_objetos', a=ejemplo1, b=ejemplo2)

objetos = np.load('mis_objetos.npz')
ejemplo1 = objetos['a']
ejemplo2 = objetos['b']
```

Los objetos a salvar, se pasan como `clave: valor` y luego la `clave` la usamos para extraer el objeto en particular.

Comment: Ya lo probé y funcionó. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Laura como eres nueva. Una forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es seleccionando la pregunta como correcta y porque no, darle también un voto positivo, eso no solo recompensará a la persona que te ayudo, si no que también servirá para posicionar mejor la pregunta y ayudar a personas que en el futuro tengan la misma duda que tú.